# Generating Crystal Report With Datasource on Runtime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a website that have no direct connection to database but a WCF service that gets data from the database using NHibernate, I need to generate a crystal report but I can't give it a datasource to the database but a dataset generated on runtime, is it possible to do that with crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports supports dataset as datasource. (if that's your question)

```
MyReport myrepo = new MyReport();
MyDataSet myds - new MyDataSet();

//load here your dataset using XML ou database query

myrepo.SetDataSource(myds);
```